# Akka STM doesn't seem to be supported in the latest versions

Tags: akka

Review lastest akka document without STM. Akka STM doesn't seem to be supported in the latest versions, why ?  Which module instead of it? Thanks!

Comment: Is it the coding problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka STM was deprecated a few years ago, as it was deemed unfit for distributed systems. For the reasoning, see [this article](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/3JWz-X5dbe8/YiV4WFG0qh0J) by Roland Kuhn about the decision to drop it.

Roland mentions [Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/agents.html#agents) in his posting, but please note that they are also deprecated.

Instead - use actors. Beyond that, it's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to achieve / which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I was looking at akka transactors which seem like a good way to deal with distributing transactions over several actors (if you have to) but they are rather dependant on akka.stm. I wonder how you can achieve this now without stm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could consider using a process manager or saga design pattern, maybe locking the actors from changing their state until the process or saga is able to commit or roll back